# Using git to make changes and then roll them back

Tags: git, git-branch

I have a web project and I need to change some banners. This will involve changing some HTML, CSS, maybe JS and adding a few images. I will use a git branch, merge it into master and deploy. No worries.

In 60 days time the marketing team will say can you put back the old banner. I cannot just wind back the whole repo because other changes will have been made in those 60 days.  Is there something I should do now to make reversing all the changes I made in the branch easy?

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to create a new branch from your `master` branch. That new branch will be identical to your current branch. Then, you can perform any necessary rollback to your `master` branch. Any changes that is done on your current branch does not affect the new branch you just created, and you can checkout the new branch if you need anything from the rolled back progress.

As a side note, a commit must be a small change. Say, if you have changed a banner of a website, you only commit the change of the banner as one commit. That way, if you only need to get back the old banner, you can rollback that one commit using `git revert <commit hash>` while keeping the following commits in your history.

Comment: So... create a new branch as a holding branch that contains the site current state?

Comment: Yes. If you create a new branch, say a new `backup` branch from the `master` branch, `backup` will contain all the history of your repo at that instance. Any changes at the `master` branch afterwards is not reflected at the `backup` branch.